# Why use printf("%s") for arguments passed to generic methods?

Tags: java, printf

```
package genericMethods;

public class OverloadedMethods {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Integer[] integerArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        Double[] doubleArray = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};
        Character[] charArray = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};

        System.out.println("A has: ");
        printArray(integerArray);
        System.out.println("B has: ");
        printArray(doubleArray);
        System.out.println("C has: ");
        printArray(charArray);
    }

    public static <T> void printArray(T[] array)
    {
        for(T element : array)
            System.out.printf("%s ", element);//why use %s instead of others? 

        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

My question is the method printArray() doesn't know what type of data is going to print out, and seems %d will occur error at run time - but isn't %s for String only ?

Comment: Please refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html. By the way, you're printing the `element` as `String`.

Comment: Because you have have a String represent anything, a float, an integer, a byte, a character, whereas the other types can only represent themselves.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The issue is that you don't KNOW what type "element" will be.  In your example, it could be Integer, Double, or Character.  That being the case, you can't use %d or %lf, because those wouldn't work for types that aren't Integer (for %d) or Double (for %lf).

%s actually works for them all, because all Object types have a .toString(), so they can all be converted to Strings for printing.

Answer (score 6):

The use of `%s` [will result](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) in the [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method being called on the object, and thus will work for any type `T`.

Comment: Actually, if the object implements `java.util.Formattable`, then the object's `formatTo` method will be invoked. This way one can reserve `toString` for sebugging, and `printf` or `format` for human use.

Answer (score 3):

Take into accoun that almost everything can be turned into a String, be it by the `toString()` method or just by appending primitive values.

When `%s` is given, it will turn whatever `element` is into a String.

Comment: Primitive values aren't accepted for generics. You can still add them, say if T is instance of Integer, but all the ints you add will be boxed to an Integer.

Comment: @Legend That issue is a little tangential to this question though - it's about how `Formatter` works, not about how generics work. You can certainly `printf` primitives (although I believe they'll be boxed), and the question actually uses the boxed types anyway.